GASを使ってGoogleアカウントのユーザーを停止状態にしたい
掲題についてですが、GASでGoogleアカウントのユーザーを停止にしたいと考えていています。
GASのリファレンスをみたり、ググってみたりしてみたのですが、そういったAPIが見当たらず、、、
GASでユーザーを停止状態にすることはできないのでしょうか。

そういう意図はないのでしょうが、文書に省略が多すぎて「他人のアカウントを停止させる」ための PoC が欲しいみたいに読めてしまいます。もしそうなら回答はつかないでしょうし、そうでないなら元質問本文を編集してください。（本人アカウントを停止させたら、どうやって復帰させるんだろう？）

英語版でも質問しているようですが 、"より詳細にする必要がある" を利用に質問がクローズされています。
